# How exactly does the P potion work?

Tags: candy-box-2

The brewing manual's description for the P potion is awfully vague:

> The P potion is a strange one. You cannot predict what it is going to
>   do. It could heal you or damage you, make you stronger or weaker, or
>   even turn you into someone (something?) else.

From this, I gather that the effects of the potion are random.  But what possible effects are there, exactly?  What can you do to influence the randomness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full logic of the P potion's effects is pretty complex. For starters:

- If you are a turtle, drinking a P potion will cause you to lose half your remaining health and then turn back into a human.
- If you have less than 8% of your health left, drinking a P potion will heal you for one of the following amounts, chosen at random: 3, 7, 10, 200, 400, 600, 50%, 65%, 80%. (EDIT: On closer inspection there's a bug here; if the game gives you a message saying you've healed 3 or 7 health, actually you've healed 10.)

Otherwise, the potion's effects are randomly determined based on the number of P potions you've drunk in the past--let's call this number P#.  Here are the possible effects along with their chances of happening:

- There is approximately a one in (P# / 2) chance of either gaining or losing either 20% or 30% of your maximum health, determined at random. The first two times you drink a P potion this is guaranteed to happen (unless you are a turtle or have less than 8% of your health remaining), since it will be a one in one chance, or 100%.  If you have drunk a lot of P potions this will become unlikely to happen, for example if you have drunk 10 potions your chances will be about 1 in 5 for this to happen (20%), for 40 potions it will be about 1 in 20 (5%), etc.
- If the above does not happen, there is approximately a one in (P# / 6) chance of getting one of four effects, chosen at random. Again, the more P potions you drink the less likely this is to happen, starting from 100% if you've drunk less than 6, and going down from there.  Here are the possible effects:

  1. You will be unable to move for a short time.
  2. You will turn into a turtle for a short time.
  3. Your health will be completely restored.
  4. You will be reduced to 10 health.
- If neither of the above happens, the game will say "Something strange is happening." You will then cast a number of spells for free in quick succession.  The spells you cast are (naturally) determined at random.  There are three different possibilities:

  1. Acid rain, Teleport, Fireball
  2. Three Acid rains, followed by a Teleport
  3. Four fireballs intermixed with Teleports (so you will teleport between each Fireball)

The exact code that determines the P potion's effects can be found by downloading the game's JavaScript [source code](https://candybox2.github.io/candybox2_uncompressed.js) and doing a search for "castPlayerPPotion".